# In F#, how to get head/tail of a seq without re-evaluating the seq

Tags: f#

I'm reading a file and I want to do something with the first line, and something else with all the other lines

```
let lines = System.IO.File.ReadLines "filename.txt" |> Seq.map (fun r -> r.Trim())

let head = Seq.head lines
let tail = Seq.tail lines
```

```

Problem: the call to `tail` fails because the `TextReader` is closed.
What it means is that the `Seq` is evaluated twice: once to get the `head` once to get the `tail`.

How can I get the firstLine and the lastLines, while keeping a `Seq` and without reevaluating the Seq ?

the signature could be, for example :

```
let fn: ('a -> Seq<'a> -> b) -> Seq<'a> -> b
```

Comment: Note that the `tail` is not the last item in the input sequence, but rather a sequence containing all of the elements of the input sequence except the first one.  There is a `Seq.last` function, though.

Comment: Yes, I know, and I really want the tail. (and my question was badly formulated)

Comment: Since Seq.cache will end up holding the whole file in memory anyway, you could also use `File.ReadAllLines`.

Comment: If the file is small, then performance is possibly best served by doing what @phoog suggests - read all at once. This can reduce head movement on a physical disk by not interleaving with other reads and writes, and it keeps the resources open for the least amount of time. This certainly can amount to something if you process thousands of files, especially in parallel. Anyway code becomes simpler.

Comment: So, is it possible to : read the file only once AND to not store in memory the file? For example, let's say I have a csv with one numerical column: I want the name of the column (first row) and the sum of the numbers of the column

Comment: I'm not able to repro this problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is probably just using [`Seq.cache`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/seq.cache%5B't%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D) to wrap your `lines` sequence:

```
let lines =
  System.IO.File.ReadLines "filename.txt"
  |> Seq.map (fun r -> r.Trim())
  |> Seq.cache
```

Of note from the documentation:

> This result sequence will have the same elements as the input sequence. The result can be enumerated multiple times. The input sequence is enumerated at most once and only as far as is necessary. Caching a sequence is typically useful when repeatedly evaluating items in the original sequence is computationally expensive or if iterating the sequence causes side-effects that the user does not want to be repeated multiple times.

Comment: If you know that you're going to read the whole file into memory anyway, why not just use `File.ReadAllLines`, which reads the whole thing into an array?

Answer (score 6):

I generally use a `seq` expression in which the `Stream` is scoped inside the expression.  That will allow you to enumerate the sequence fully before the stream is disposed.  I usually use a function like this:

```
let readLines file =
    seq {
        use stream = File.OpenText file
        while not stream.EndOfStream do
            yield stream.ReadLine().Trim()
    }
```

Then you should be able to call `Seq.head` and get the first line in the fail, and `Seq.last` to get the last line in the file.  I think this will technically create two different enumerators though.  If you want to only read the file exactly one time, then materializing the sequence to a list or using a function like `Seq.cache` will be your best option.

Answer (score 0):

I had an important use case for this, where I am using Seq.unfold to read a large number of blocks with REST reads, and sequentially processing each block, with further REST reads.

The reading of the sequence had to be both "lazy" but also cached to avoid duplicate re-evaluation (with every `Seq.tail` operation).

Hence finding this question and the accepted answer (`Seq.cache`). Thanks!

I experimented with `Seq.cache` and discovered that it worked as claimed (ie, lazy and avoid re-evaluation), but with one noteworthy condition - the first five elements of the sequence are always read first (and retained with 'cache'), so experiments on five or smaller numbers won't show lazy evaluation. However, after five, lazy evaluation kicks in for each element.

This code can be used to experiment. Try it for 5, and see no lazy evaluation, and then 10, and see each element after 5 being 'lazy' read, as required. Also remove `Seq.cache` to see the problem we are addressing (re-evaluation)

```
// Get a Sequence of numbers.
let getNums n  = seq { for i in 1..n do printfn "Yield { %d }" i; yield i}

// Unfold a sequence of numbers
let unfoldNums (nums : int seq) =
    nums
    |> Seq.unfold
        (fun (nums : int seq) ->
            printfn "unfold: nums = { %A }" nums
            if Seq.isEmpty nums then
                printfn "Done"
                None
            else
                let num = Seq.head nums // Value to yield
                let tl = Seq.tail nums // Next State. CAUSES RE-EVALUTION!
                printfn "Yield: < %d >, tl =  { %A }" num tl
                Some (num,tl))
    
// Get n numbers as a sequence, then unfold them as a sequence
// Observe that with 'Seq.cache' input is not re-evaluated unnecessarily, 
// and also that lazy evaulation kicks in for n > 5
let experiment n =
    getNums n
    |> Seq.cache
    // Without cache, Seq.tail causes the sequence to be re-evaluated
    |> unfoldNums
    |> Seq.iter (fun x -> printfn "Process: %d" x)
```